# How to check in GAP whether two groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, gap

Let $G,H$ be two Groups. How to check with GAP whether they are isomorphic or not?

For example, GAP has `IsNilpotentGroup` to check whether the group $G$ is nilpotent. Is there a similar function named like `AreIsomorphicGroups` to check whether $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic or not?

Comment: Look for the function [IsomorphismGroups](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap40.html#X81B79CC27F47D429) in GAP's reference manual. But also have a look at [this](http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2009/002426.html).

Comment: The question is not clearly formulated. Are you looking for a command to check isomorphism or to the code of the function which does this? Assuming the former, follow the link to `IsomorphismGroup` given by @Jean-ClaudeArbaut and observe two other functions suggested in its documentation. It also matters whether do you want to check that the groups are isomorphic or not, or do you need to find a particular isomorphism.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I want a program for this do you want to check that the groups are isomorphic or not? For Example this program there exists for check  nilpotentcy of group $G$, " gap> IsNilpotentGroup<G>;" . Do there same program for to check isimorphism between two Groups?

Comment: `IsomorphismGroups` returns the actual isomorphism or `fail` if the groups are not isomorphic. For small groups, you can just calculate `IdGroup` for both and check that they are equal - that's why `IdGroup` is mentioned in the manual section for `IsomorphismGroups`.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov. Thanks. How I can use of this in this GAP program?      gap>    If  $G\cong H$ then  else .....fi;

Comment: @A.G: `if IsomorphismGroups(G,H) <> fail then ...` or (after checking that the order of the group is <2000 and not 1024) checking that `IdGroup(G)=IdGroup(H)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two aspects here: how to search such information in GAP, and how to actually check the isomorphism of two groups.

First, the OP was quite close to guessing the name of the function, since most of the documented GAP functions follow [these naming conventions](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap5.html#X81F732457F7BC851). Functions that return `true` or `false` usually have the name of the form `IsSomething` (even in the cases when `AreSomething` could make sense). So one could expect that GAP has something named like `IsIsomorph...`.

Making such a guess, one could now use the help system to find all help entries **starting** with `IsIsom`. To do this, enter `?IsIsom` in GAP (one could also try `??IsIsom` to find all entries containing a **substring** `IsIsom`). This will produce a list of entries, and those which are relevant are

```
ANUPQ (not loaded): IsIsomorphicPGroup
```

and

```
SONATA (not loaded): IsIsomorphicGroup
```

(this also demonstrates a very useful feature of the help system - searching in the manuals of packages even when they are not loaded).

Now in more details about the actual isomorphism check. If one would open the documentation of SONATA's `IsIsomorphicGroup`, that would lead to the GAP  function `IsomorphismGroups` which constructs and returns the actual isomorphism, if it is possible, or returns `fail` if the groups are non-isomorphic (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap40.html#X7B536A32827788C6)). For example:

```
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(8);
<pc group of size 8 with 3 generators>
gap> H:=Group( (1,5)(2,3)(4,8)(6,7), (1,2)(3,8)(4,6)(5,7) );
Group([ (1,5)(2,3)(4,8)(6,7), (1,2)(3,8)(4,6)(5,7) ])
gap> IsomorphismGroups(H,G);
[ (1,5)(2,3)(4,8)(6,7), (1,2)(3,8)(4,6)(5,7) ] -> [ f1*f3, f1*f2 ]
gap> T:=Group([ (1,7,4,3)(2,8,6,5), (1,4)(2,6)(3,7)(5,8) ]);
Group([ (1,7,4,3)(2,8,6,5), (1,4)(2,6)(3,7)(5,8) ])
gap> IsomorphismGroups(T,G);
fail
```

One could inspect the source code of this function entering

```
PageSource(IsomorphismGroups);
```

to see that before attempting to construct the isomorphism it does some checks of necessary conditions and will immediately return `fail` if e.g. the groups have different orders or different number of conjugacy classes. Also, for groups of the order that allows identification of the group in the GAP Small Groups Library (see `IdGroup` [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap50.html#X83044B9D7E3BDF35)) it checks that both groups have the same ID and returns fail if not.

This may be useful if one is only interested whether two groups are isomorphic, but not interested in the actual homomorphism: in this case `G` and `H` are isomorphic if and only if `IdGroup(G)=IdGroup(H)`. In the example above, we have:

```
gap> IdGroup(G);
[ 8, 3 ]
gap> IdGroup(H);
[ 8, 3 ]
gap> IdGroup(T);
[ 4, 1 ]
```

Identification using `IdGroup` is possible for all orders in the library except for the orders $512$ and $1536$ and except for the orders $p^5$, $p^6$ and $p^7$ above $2000$ (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap50.html#X814D329A7B59F0EB)). Also note that ANUPQ package has an undocumented function `IdStandardPresented512Group` which provides identification for groups of order 512.

This approach is used by the SONATA package which provides a function `IsIsomorphicGroup` (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/sonata/htm/ref/CHAP001.htm#SSEC006.1)) which returns `true` or `false` dependently on whether the two groups are isomorphic or not:

```
gap> LoadPackage("sonata");
true
gap> IsIsomorphicGroup(G,H);
true
gap> IsIsomorphicGroup(G,T);
false
```

To inspect the code of `IsIsomorphicGroup`, first call `LoadPackage("sonata");` and then enter

```
PageSource(ApplicableMethod(IsIsomorphicGroup,[Group((1,2)),Group((2,3))]));
```

Then one could also see that this checks some necessary conditions before doing actual work in the generic method which just checks that `IsomorphismGroups( G, H ) <> fail`. These necessary conditions could work fast for small groups but not work very efficiently for very large ones (e.g. comparing the number of elements of each order), so this should be used with care.

In case of a $p$-group, the ANUPQ package (requires compilation, not available in the GAP distribution for Windows) provides the function `IsIsomorphicPGroup` (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/anupq-3.1.4/doc/chap4.html#X854389FC780BB178)) which is applicable only to groups of prime power order and may be more efficient in this case. See more details about the algorithm it uses [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/anupq-3.1.4/doc/chap2.html#X807FB2EC85E6648D).

For very large groups, checking whether they are isomorphic or not may be quite time-consuming. One could try to calculate some other invariants to try to show that they are different, and/or try to find better representation of the group (e.g. convert a group given by generators and relators to a permutation group) so that GAP will operate with it faster. In case of any challenging examples, I suggest to post them in separate questions.