# How to find with GAP a group that is isomorphic to its inner automorphisms group

Tags: group-theory, gap

Let $G$ be a group such that we Know  that there  exists some group $H$ such  that $$G\cong Inn(H),$$ where Inn(G) is Inner automorphisms Group of $H$.

Now How by GAP we can find $H$?

Thank you

Comment: If $G\cong Inn(H)$ then also, $G\cong Inn(H\times A)$ for any abelian group $A$. Hence $H$ is not uniquely determined by $G$. The only possible way could be checking some properties of $G$, and some trial-and-error method.

Comment: @pGroups: Yes there exists many groups $H$, such that $G\cong  Inn(H)$. I want only one group $H$ such that $G\cong Inn(H).$

Comment: The question in the title doesn't seem to match the question in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to find an example of such group using the GAP Small Groups Library.

First one should find out how to check this property for a given group. Typing `??Inner` in GAP, you should be able to find `InnerAutomorphismsAutomorphismGroup` and `AutomorphismGroup` and then proceed like suggested in the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715371/what-is-the-isomorphism-program-in-gap). I suggest to check first that the order of $Inn(G)$ is equal to the order of $G$ - clearly, if not, then they are non-isomorphic.

As soon as you can check this property for a single group, you can start to search systematically through the GAP small groups library - see e.g. an example from my GAP Software Carpentry lesson [here](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups.html).