# Explicit Isomorphism Between Two $p$-Groups in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gap, p-groups, computational-algebra

I was trying to find an isomorphism between two $p$-groups, say $G_1$ and $G_2$ in GAP.

I am using "anupq" and "sonata" package and both the groups are Pcp-groups. The available GAP commands, I found, are

- IsIsomorphicPGroup : Only tests for isomorphism but does not return any explicit isomorphism.
- IsomorphismGroups : Extremely slow as I am dealing with $p$-groups of high orders.

Using "IsIsomorphicPGroup" I found that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic but I can not find a way to compute any explicit isomorphism. I was stuck.

It will be really helpful to me if someone suggest a GAP command and/or some method in GAP to find an explicit isomorphism.

Thanks in advance.

**Addendum:**
Pasteable descriptions of the groups are given below:

```
G1:=PcGroupCode(955640327050884159907086343326037903249608121254657344251813252604839841049205\
928253819936651413089137658451601883818586226317596151455694910726535214017948\
592364716601333424997621599040461436158518049878550005884433797152129115721878\
3355,1594323);

G2:=PcGroupCode(119880391495293774233093786967542939562883947810316663646225196199229505601219\
647372529980143720441259762954784595217079537995955140290437544251478057697281\
21121849582846112554279125935293754034335404366719215627371184752858002092155,1594323);
```

Comment: I presume you mean not "Pcp" (polycyclic package) but `PcGroup` (library). Are you loading the `autpgrp' package? Can you somehow post (e.g. use `GapInputPcGroup`) what the groups are?

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks. Two groups are actually Pcp group, which I converted to Pc group using "IsomorphismPcGroup" to test for isomorphism using "IsISomorphicPGroup". I am using "autpgrp" pkg also. The description of the groups, found by "GapInputPcGroup" are really long. I have added those in my question. Please have a look. Your suggestion will be really helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Sorry, I do not know how to recover a group from `GapInputPcGroup` . I will try to find a better way to post the groups. However, any general suggestion for determining an explicit isomorphism between large $p$-groups in GAP will also be really helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @usermath That's much better, and copy-pastes perfectly.  Off-hand I'm not seeing any way to make this an easy problem, as in general the isomorphism problem is difficult.  With more knowledge of the particulars of the groups (what they come from, what they "do", etc.) one might be able to see at least why an isomorphism exists, if not a constructive way of writing one down.  The code for IsIsomorphicPGroup is presumably open source, so have you tried looking that up to see if its proof is constructive?  If so you could just modify the function to the return the isomorphism.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Thanks. It is user ahulpke, who have edited the post for the pastable code. A big thanks to him. As for isomorphism, I have seen the code for `IsISomorphicPGroup` but it possibly compares `StdPresentation` of the $p$-groups. I am not sure how to recover an isomorphism from there. Any suggestion will be greatly helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks a lot for adding the pasteable description of the groups.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715371/how-to-check-in-gap-whether-two-groups-are-isomorphic/1715995#1715995 - is that of any help?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thanks. I have seen that post. It describes how to determine if two groups are isomorphic or not. That I have already done. My aim is to find an explicit isomorphism. Using `IsomorphismGroups` is not helping since it is taking too much time.

Comment: I am still in need for this, any suggestion will be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use `anupq` to compute an explicit isomorphism; To do this, use `EpimorphismStandardPresentation` on the two input groups; this actually gives an isomorphism here. However, the image is an fp group, where we cannot effectively do all computations we need. So we first convert the images to pc groups q1 and a2, and construct new epis on these. Since the groups G1 and G2 are isomorphic, their standard presesentations are equal, which allows use to trivially write down an iso between q1 and q2. Combining everything, we get the desired isomorphism. The following shows how to actually do this here.

In addition, I [logged an issue on the anupq issue tracker](https://github.com/gap-packages/anupq/issues/22) to remind me to implement that for the next `anupq` releases.

```
gap> LoadPackage("anupq", false);
true
gap>
gap> G1:=PcGroupCode(9556403270508841599070863433260379032496081212546573442518132526048398410492059282538199366514130891376584516018838185862263175961514556949107265352140179485923647166013334249976215990404614361585180498785500058844337971521291157218783355,1594323);
<pc group of size 1594323 with 13 generators>
gap>
gap> G2:=PcGroupCode(11988039149529377423309378696754293956288394781031666364622519619922950560121964737252998014372044125976295478459521707953799595514029043754425147805769728121121849582846112554279125935293754034335404366719215627371184752858002092155,1594323);
<pc group of size 1594323 with 13 generators>
gap>
gap> epi1:=EpimorphismStandardPresentation(G1);;
gap> epi2:=EpimorphismStandardPresentation(G2);;
gap> q1:=PcGroupFpGroup(Range(epi1));;
gap> q2:=PcGroupFpGroup(Range(epi2));;
gap>
gap> iso_pc := GroupHomomorphismByImages(q1, q2);
[ f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13 ] -> [ f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13 ]
gap> Assert(0, iso_pc <> fail); # verify the two groups are really isomorphic
gap>
gap> epi1_pc := epi1 * GroupHomomorphismByImages(Range(epi1), q1);;
gap> IsBijective(epi1_pc); # force GAP to verify that the map is bijective
true
gap> epi2_pc := epi2 * GroupHomomorphismByImages(Range(epi2), q2);;
gap> IsBijective(epi2_pc); # force GAP to verify that the map is bijective
true
gap>
gap> iso := epi1_pc * iso_pc * InverseGeneralMapping(epi2_pc);
[ f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13 ] -> [ f1^2*f2^2*f4^2*f5*f6^2*f7^2*f8^2*f9*f10*f11^2*f12, f2*f4^2*f6^2*f7*f9*f10*f12^2*f13^2, f3^2*f5*f6^2*f7*f9^2,
  f4*f7*f8*f9^2*f10*f11^2*f13, f5^2*f7*f8*f9^2*f10^2*f11, f6*f7*f12^2*f13, f7^2*f8^2, f8*f10^2*f11*f12*f13, f9^2*f10^2*f12*f13, f10*f11*f13^2, f11^2*f13, f12*f13, f13^2 ]
gap>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is really nice.