# Isomorphism between two p-groups

Tags: gap, magma-cas

I've been looking for an explicit isomorphism between the following  two groups (h and g):

```
gap> q := FreeGroup( "x", "y","z");; 
gap> g := q / [ q.1^25, q.2^5,q.3^5*q.1^-10,q.1^-1*q.2^-1*q.1*q.2*q.1^-5,q.1^-1*q.3^-1*q.1*q.3*q.2^-1,q.2^-1*q.3^-1*q.2*q.3 ]; 
gap> f := FreeGroup( "a", "b","c");; 
gap> h := f / [ f.1^25, f.2^5,f.3^5*f.1^-10,f.1^-1*f.2^-1*f.1*f.2,f.1^-1*f.3^-1*f.1*f.3*f.2^-1,f.2^-1*f.3^-1*f.2*f.3*f.1^-10 ];
```

I applied the GAP's Code at the link:
[Explicit Isomorphism Between Two $p$-Groups in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249231/explicit-isomorphism-between-two-p-groups-in-gap?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, it did not work for me. FYI, I loaded the "anupq" and "sonata" pakages,
and used IsomorphismGroups and IsISomorphicPGroup.
They are, however, extremely slow at computing the isomorphism between P-groups of a high order.

I'm not sure if MAGMA has a code that does the same thing for me. If so, could you please share it?

Any assistance with this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it did not work for me"? Do you get an error, or does the code run forever, or something else? On my GAP installation, `IsomorphismGroups( g, h )` produces an isomorphism in ~400ms.

Comment: Convert to `PcGroups`,  usig `IsomorphismPGroup`, then the calculation (use `IsomorphismGroups`) is instantaneous on my laptop.

Comment: > G1:=IsomorphismPcGroup(g);;
gap> H1:=IsomorphismPcGroup(h);;
gap> IsomorphismGroups(G1,H1);
#I  Forcing finiteness test
Error, no method found! F\
or debugging hints\
 type ?Recovery fr\
om NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choi\
ce method found fo\
r `IsFinite' on 1 \
arguments at /Applications/\
Gap.app/Contents/g\
ap/lib/methsel2.g:
249 called from
IsFinite( G 
 ); at /Applicatio\
ns/Gap.app/Content\
s/gap/lib/morpheus\
.gi:2233 called from
<function "Isomorp\
hismGroups">( <arg\
uments> )
 called from read-\
eval loop at *stdin*:27
type 'quit;' to qu\
it to outer loop

Comment: Above is my attempt. GAP returns an error. It would be great to share your attempts because I feel something went wrong with mine but am unsure.

Comment: Which version of GAP are you running? (and first thing, call `Size` on the finitely presented groups)

Comment: GAP 4.11.0 of 29-Feb-2020

Comment: @sTertooy It will be better if there is another code as IsomorphismGroups( g, h ) does not work when we go to some groups of order 5^5=3125.

Comment: @MrJ Looking at your code, you are storing the isomorphisms in `G1` and `G2`. You should be storing the images of these isomorphisms instead.

Comment: @sTertooy I need it in terms of x,y,z and a,b,c, GAP gave me the following 
 gap> H:=Image(IsomorphismPcGroup(h));
Group(
[ f1^4, f3, f2 ])
gap> G:=Image(IsomorphismPcGroup(g));
Group(
[ f1^4, f3*f4^4, 
  f2 ])
gap> IsomorphismGroups(H,G);
[ f1^4, f3, f2 
 ] -> 
[ f2*f3*f4^4, 
  f3^3*f4, 
  f1^3*f2*f3*f4^3 
 ]
gap> IsomorphismGroups(G,H);
[ f1^4, f3*f4^4, 
  f2 ] -> 
[ f2^3*f3*f4, 
  f3^4*f4^3, 
  f1^3*f3^2*f4 ]

Comment: @MrJ In that case, save the isomorphisms from FpGroups to PcGroups in separate variables and compose them with the isomorphism between the two PcGroups:
`isog := IsomorphismPcGroup( g );;isoh := IsomorphismPcGroup( h );;` 
`G1 := Image( isog );;G2 := Image( isoh );;`
`isoG1G2 := IsomorphismGroups( G1, G2 );;`
`iso := isog * isoG1G2 * InverseGeneralMapping( isoh )`

Comment: @sTertooy that works. Thank you very much.